# Creating a web application that communicates with another web application seamlessly?

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, struts2, flask, communication

I am trying to develop a web application that can communicate with another web application. App1 is an app developed using Angular.js and Struts2. This apps sole purpose is to perform search queries on several databases and returning the information about the products for the user to view. App2, the current app I am developing, will be developed using Angular.js and Flask/Python. This app will be responsible for storing the products the user selects in a shopping cart and allowing the user to make a purchase.

I am stuck as to how to get the two applications to communicate(passing login information, selected items ids, etc.) with eachother.

I have tried passing information via a url redirect (http://www.example.com/?myVar=someData&...) but Angular is giving me a lot of trouble to try and get around that. Even if I can get this to work, I think it would be insecure as data the user shouldn't know will be exposed in the url.

My second thought would be to somehow access the session data from App1 in App2 but that could also lead to security issues.

My final thought would be to some how make a call to App1 that returns a json object that can be parsed in App2 but I am not entirely sure how to pass that information along.

How can I get the two applications to communicate with each other?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion this isn't really within the scope of AngularJS. However, I believe that the best, most accepted practice for communication between web applications in this day and age is RESTful Web Services.

It's not a small topic, but once you get the concept behind it you can use it in *any* programming language that supports web applications (Java which I'm assuming you're using because of struts has multiple REST libraries, I prefer Jersey but that's just me).

It's also an amazing way to use your Angular front end to talk with its own back end. The entire Angular $resource framework is built around the idea of using RESTful services.

Check out this link on Wikipedia for a brief synopsis of what makes a service RESTful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Applied_to_web_services

Now, that applies to most of what you asked. As far as login information is concerned, that's going to depend on your security implementation. A lot of times you can put information like that in the header of a web services request, and only accept requests that come from trusted servers, etc. but there's a good bit of stuff to understand there. It's an entirely separate topic.

Hopefully this helps you get started. Let me know if you'd like more information or pointers.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely helped in getting me started. I've actually come up with a solution that I will explore with passing data in the URL. Basically I can encrypt the data together and pass it to the other application. The secret key can be shared in the properties/settings files of the two applications.

Thanks for the help again

Comment: No problem. Like I said, feel free to hit me up with questions. Learning REST will continue to pay off for a long time to come career-wise.